# Laravel: Eloquent "join", how to get only a property of the referred table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model `A` and a model `B`.

I made the relations between them, so i can do A->B->property.

But now I'm facing some problems.

I need to make a query and get only that B->property, not the B object.

So i use this:

```
A::with(['B'])->get()
```

But then a get a property called B in A with the complete B model.
Is there anyway to achieve something like this.

```
A::with(['B->property'])->get()
```

So then in the B property inside `A` I get the `B->property` instead the `B` object.

Is it possible?

PS: I can't use the query builder because i need that eloquent model.

Comment: Do you define relationship in the model for `A` and `B`.

Comment: Yes, i can do A->B and get B, but i need to do something like A->B->property inside the "query".

Comment: what kind of relationship you create between `A` and `B`

Comment: inside the A model i have the function B() wich returns this->hasOne...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this article will help you out:
http://laraveldaily.com/why-use-appends-with-accessors-in-eloquent/

You can put
`$appends = ['property']` in your model to add a `property` field to your model.

Then, with an accessor method in the model you can describe how to populate that field (ie: with a field from another model via relationship).

It seems like that ought to give you what you want.

Comment: Nice, i think i can do what i want with these tips. Very thank you!

Comment: Sorry, there you have it. I cant upvote, 15 reputation neede :P

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

In your `A` model:

```
protected $appends = ['property'];


public function B()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\B');
    }

public function getPropertyAttribute()
    {
        return $this->B()->property;
    }
```

then `A->property` will give you `B->property`. Change `model` name and `property` name as per your requirement.

Comment: This is exactly the approach suggested in the article I posted below...and elaborated on in my answer. I think this will work to do what you're trying to do @Sampudon

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40473570/7318884) by @shoieb0101 did not work for me because I had a `belongsTo` relationship rather than `hasOne`. If this is the case for you too, you just need to modify the accessor function as illustrated below.

```
protected $appends = ['property'];

public function B()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\B');
    }

public function getPropertyAttribute()
    {
        return $this->B()->first()->property;
    }
```

**Note:** I added `->first()` in since `belongsTo` returns an array of results, but we can get the property from a single result only.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to constrain eagerloaded queries:

try

```
A::with(["B" => function($query){
   $query->select('property');
}])->get();
```

Comment: that's still going to give him A->B->property.